# How do I make a "Sticky message" that stays always on the bottom of the channel. (Discord.py)

Tags: python, json, database, discord, discord.py

While working on my Discord bot, I found another bot that does "sticky messages". That basically means that an embed or message will always stay at the bottom and the second message will be deleted.

## Example

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Hr3e.gif]

## Code:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == 1206246422324715580:
        if message.author == bot.user:
            return
        else:
            msg = await message.channel.fetch_message(1208866913426473021)
            new_embed = msg.embeds[0].copy()
            await message.channel.send(embed=new_embed)
            # await new_embed.delete()
    else:
        return
```

But it didn't delete the old message. I'm thinking of having something with a database and JSON. I want to make it look like the GIF I sent before.

Comment: I believe you will have to store the id of the last message to access it. I wouldn't recommend using JSON though.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is very simple. It requires a couple of steps.

1. Save the message ID, content, and channel ID to a database (this could be JSON, but SQL is the best way to go)
2. Every time a new message is sent, delete the old message (using the database to get that old message) and send the new message to the channel.
3. Once the new message is sent, save and update that new message ID in the database.

Of course, you need to create other systems for deleting certain rows in the database once the user decides they don't want a sticky message anymore. However, I won't cover that here (at least for now), as it is out of the context of your question.

### Step one: Creating the database

For this, I'll be using [sqllite3 for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)

```py
# --- SQL startup ---
con = sqlite3.connect("sticky_messages.db")  # connect to the database
cur = con.cursor()  # create the cursor
try:
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE sticky(guild_id, channel_id, message_id, message)")  # attempt to create the table
    print("Created new sticky table for sticky_messages")
except sqlite3.OperationalError:
    print("Found existing table for sticky")  # if the table already exists
```

The above is very simple. We're just setting up the sqqlite3 database.

## For Pycord

### Creating the creation slash command

```py
@bot.slash_command()
async def set_up_sticky_messages(ctx, msg_content: str, channel: discord.TextChannel):
    ref = cur.execute(f"""SELECT * FROM sticky WHERE channel_id=?""", (channel.id,))
    ref_fetch = ref.fetchall()

    if ref_fetch:
        return await ctx.respond("You already have a sticky message setup")

    msg = await channel.send(msg_content)
    cur.execute(f"""INSERT INTO sticky 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);""", (ctx.guild.id, channel.id, msg.id, msg_content))
    con.commit()  # save to db
    await ctx.respond("Created sticky message")
```

#### How this works:

1. We first check to see if there is already a sticky message entry in the database. If there is, we return an error message.
2. We then send the message into the channel that the user provides (if you want to use an embed here, it's very simple)
3. We save the related info (as mentioned above) into the database to be used later

#### This outputs:

[image: Output of the slash command]

### The message event

The message event is used for getting and deleting the past message as well as sending the new sticky message.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    ref = cur.execute(f"""SELECT * FROM sticky WHERE channel_id=?""", (msg.channel.id,))
    ref_fetch = ref.fetchall()

    if not ref_fetch:  # No record found in database
        return

    channel_id = ref_fetch[0][1]
    message_id = ref_fetch[0][2]
    message_content = ref_fetch[0][3]
    channel = await bot.fetch_channel(channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(message_id)

    await message.delete()  # delete old message
    new_msg = await channel.send(message_content)  # send new message

    cur.execute("UPDATE sticky SET message_id = ? WHERE channel_id= ?", (new_msg.id, channel_id))
    con.commit()  # update db
```

#### How this works

1. We first check to see if the message is in the database. If it isn't, we return nothing.
2. If it is in the database, we delete the old message and send a new one. We update the database's ID with the new message ID.

## For Discord.py

It should be very similar database-wise. The only thing you'd need to change is how you're handling the slash commands.

## Final output

### Before:

[image: Before sending message]

### After:

[image: After sending message]

Comment: I never did with slashes. It is not showing

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/K2Gzvt4aXbQ7.png

Comment: my bot is not there

Comment: @RadarKolar if you’re not using Pycord, you have to program that part yourself. It’s very simple though. Just change the handlers to discord.py handlers and you’ll be good to go

Comment: It is working now. but it's at every message it gives an error: `Unknown Message`. And other command doesn't work

Comment: @RadarKolar Does your bot have the proper intents enabled in the developer portal?

Comment: I enabled all and still other commands don't work

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/i9OlipTS6sbU.png

Comment: @RadarKolar "don't work" doesn't give me any information to work off of. Tell me if you get any errors

Comment: No, not any errors

Comment: If you want you can message me on discord `radar014`